# complicated coupled equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $a\neq 0,b\neq 0,c=0,a\neq d$
>
> $\dot{x}=ax+by$
>
> $\dot{y}=cx+dy$

so, $y\left ( t \right )=c_{2}e^{\int (d) dt}$

Thus, $\dot{x} = ax+by \left(t \right)$

I cannot seem to find any ways to solve for $x\left ( t \right )$. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: A general method: define $\vec{z}=\pmatrix{x\\y}$ and $A=\pmatrix{a & b\\ c & d}$ so that the system can be written $\frac{d\vec{z}}{dt} = A\vec{z}$. This is a [matrix differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation), see the linked page for how to solve it.

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ and $d$ constant or functions of $x$?

Comment: For this particular problem since you know $c=0$ then it's simpler. Substitute the solution the solution you found for $y$ in the equation for $x$ to get $\dot{x} = ax + bc_2e^{dt}$. This is a normal first order ODE which can be solved by completing the differential on the left hand side $\dot{x} - ax = e^{at}\frac{d}{dt}[xe^{-at}]$, moving the $e^{ax}$ term to the right hand side and integrating.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald They're just constants.

Answer (score 0):

if the coefficients are constant then you can use Laplace transform and write the equation is S-doman:
$$sX(s)-x(0)=aX(s)+bY(s)$$
$$sY(s)-y(0)=cX(s)+bY(s)$$
no you have a linear system of equation that can be solve easily use Cramer's formula or even simpler by substitution. after solving take the inverse Transform.
so cause they are constants and assuming that we know the value of functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ at time instant $t=0$ then above system is a Linear System of Equations in Terms of $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$. since $c=0$ one can solve for $Y(s)$ and get: $$Y(s)=\frac{y(0)}{s-b}$$ so simply $y(t)=y(0)e^{bt}u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is unit step function (A.K.A. Heaviside Step Function). now by substituting $Y(s)=\frac{y(0)}{s-b}$ in first equation we can get:
$$X(s)=\frac{x(0)}{s-a}+\frac{by(0)}{(s-a)(s-b)}=\frac{x(0)+\frac{by(0)}{a-b}}{s-a}+\frac{\frac{by(0)}{b-a}}{s-b}$$ so we get $x(t)$ as below:
$$x(t)=(x(0)+\frac{by(0)}{a-b})e^{at}u(t)+\frac{by(0)}{b-a}e^{bt}u*(t)$$
$$y(t)=y(0)e^{bt}u(t)$$
all above conclusion is valid when $a,b,c,d$ are constants and $c=0$. otherwise you must solve it like a Homogeneous first order differential equation with the method mentioned by @Winther in comment above. but when $a,b,c,d$ are constants and $c=0$ the solution in closed form is mentioned above.